# Are Gradle, GWT, Jetty, and MongoDB compatible with each other?

Tags: mongodb, gradle, gwt, jetty

I am writing code with simple GWT for at least 5 years but sth is missing in my projects. My code is not portable or transparent enough.

Is there anyone know any Tutorial to Use Gradle, GWT, Jetty, and MongoDB, all together at the same time? Or  are some not compatible with each other, that i am looking sth impossible?

I am learning some of above one by one, but a minimalist tutorial which covers them all, to create simple app, would be best thing in my life.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your question. There is a gradle plugin for GWT, checkout this example: https://github.com/zak905/gradle-gwt-example. There is nothing that prevents from writing a GWT app, with a backend calling a MongoDB database, and making everything run on a Jetty server

Comment: I have already dismiss using gradle (as I couldn't understand it) and I found how to ask THE question: by using "Netbeans.NewProject.Maven.ProjectFromArcheType", is there a working build for GWT embededJavaServer(Jetty/Tomcat...), embededSQLServer(MariaDB/MySQLDB)

Comment: I have recently migrate to Maven finally with using Netbeans :"https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes"."Generate a project".

Comment: my gwt war works fine on standalone Tomcat9 server. And I saw some tomcat7 plug already added on maven pom. Hence, I tried adding action to netbeans by: ProjectProperties.Actions.AddCustom(name:runTomcat,executeGoals:tomcat7:run). Then I right click the project and RunMaven.runTomcat. I THINK the tomcat7 started on embeded mode. But I get the error on Firefox console ("Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/AutoSQLWeb/app/app.nocache.js”). I am stucked again.

Comment: At last I make tomcat7-maven-plugin run. I decreased the version to 2.1. Then I remake another Goal as "clean package tomcat7:exec-war -e". Then I changed the location of the jar file created (AutoSQLWeb\AutoSQLWeb-server\target\AutoSQLWeb-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT-war-exec.jar), then I run the command (java -jar AutoSQLWeb-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT-war-exec.jar -extractDirectory=webapps). now the tomcat is working ok, but every time I revized my jar, tomcat deletes the webapps directory, and all my uploads in it!!! Before I start embeding a sql server to my jar, I need to figure this out :(